# What is the difference b/w authenticate() and login() in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I want to understand the difference b/w both

```
user = authenticate(
    username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
    password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
)
login(request, user)
```

Comment: `authenticate()` to verify a set of credentials. It takes credentials as keyword arguments, username and password for the default case, checks them against each authentication backend, and returns a User object if the credentials are valid for a backend. and To log a user in, from a view, use `login()`. It takes an HttpRequest object and a User object. login() saves the user’s ID in the session, using Django’s session framework. More details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **authenticate()** method accepts username and password and validates if the the credentials entered are those of valid user. If yes, it returns an user object.

The **Login** method takes an **HttpRequest** object and auth_user object . and Logs the user in and binds him not only to the request object but also in Session.